# Loop infinito em listagem

Tags: javascript

Fiz esse código para apresentar os jogos cadastrados, mas a página não finaliza o carregamento.

Está em *loop* infinito? Se sim, por quê? Como poderia arrumar?

```
window.addEventListener("load", showJogos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Jogos'))), false);

function showJogos(loadJogos){
  var times = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Times'));
  listar = $('#mostrarJogos');
  if (loadJogos == null) {
    listar.append('<h3 class="col s12 center-align"> Nenhum jogo registrado</h3>');
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < loadJogos.length; i++) {
      var viewTime1 = loadJogos[i].time1
      var viewTime2 = loadJogos[i].time2

      for (var t = 0; t < times.length; i++) {
        if (viewTime1 == times[t].id){
          for (var u = 0; u < times.length; i++) {
            if (viewTime2 == times[u].id) {
                listar.append('<h3 class="col l5 right-align">' + times[t].nome + '</h3><img class="col l2" src="img/x.png"><h3 class="col l5"> ' + times[u].nome + '</h3>');
                break;
            }
          }
        break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (var t = 0; t < times.length; i++)`

Aqui estás incrementando o `i` em vez do `t`, assim o loop vai continuar pra sempre, pois o `t` nunca vai sair do lugar. Troque pra `t++`

Mesma coisa aqui:

`for (var u = 0; u < times.length; i++)`

troque para `u++`

Comment: Percebi isso agora kkk. muito obrigado heim :D

Comment: Como marco ela como resolvido?

Comment: Só clicar no ícone de certo embaixo dos ícones de voto da minha resposta